# NSUserDefaults cause Exception under iOS6

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, ios6

The `NSUserDefaults` causes Exception under iOS6 SDK, the exception is below:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3527a2a3 0x32d7a97f 0x351cb55f 0x352020d3 0xe2f9d 0x351cb037 0x372a1d91 0x372aa13b 0xcd813 0x34e36f1f 0x34e379a9 0x36d5d35d 0x3524f173 0x3524f117 0x3524df99 0x351c0ebd 0x351c0d49 0x32e762eb 0x34c38301 0xcc20f 0xc5e40)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

here is the code:

```
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *shortVersionString = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
// the shortVersionString is 2.0.1
[ud setBool:YES forKey:@"hasBeenLaunched"];
[ud setObject:shortVersionString forKey:@"CurrentVersion"];
```

If I comment out `[ud setBool:YES forKey:@"hasBeenLaunched"];` and `[ud setObject:shortVersionString forKey:@"CurrentVersion"];` the app works fine.

Anyone can help? Thanks very much!

Comment: can you post your code so its readable?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a log message, you will find that the version string is nil. You cannot write a nil to the defaults, which is the reason for the failure:

```
NSString *shortVersionString = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSLog(@"Bet this is nil: %@", shortVersionString);
NSLog(@"Get ready for crash");
[ud setObject:shortVersionString forKey:@"CurrentVersion"];
NSLog(@"Guess I was wrong - no crash :-(");
```

Answer (score 1):

I register a `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` notification, if change the NSUserDefaults settings, the notification method called. Some variables are nil before the first launch, and I will save those variables to NSUserDefaults, so the crash occurred.